# Why is creating an object inside an argument without naming the object possible?

Tags: java, object, constructor, arguments

I created a Dimension and a Point object but I do not need to name both of these objects and call its constructor inside the argument of the method call. May I have an explanation why this is possible? I have been far too used to giving my objects name that I am need explanation to my question.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Point;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

        public GameFrame()
        {

            // call this method to the GameFrame object 
            // if you do not call this method the JFrame subclass will not actually close
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // set size to an appropriate size
            // create a dimension object 
            setSize(new Dimension(600,600));

            // upon creating the object set the location of the frame to the center of the screen
            setLocation(new Point (500,300));

            // prevent the user from resizing the GameFrame object
            setResizable(false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Objects don't have names. You're thinking of variables :-p You don't need a variable here because you need to maintain a reference to neither the location nor the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
```

you are actually saving a reference of the `Dimension` object as you create the object and pass it to the method.

This works well and recommended if you need not use the object further for any computation separately.

Comment: So I can save a lot of memory. I don't understand the memory part. I heard memory a few times but i dont understand how memory works. But also where does memory come from and why is it consumed when I create objects?

Answer (score 3):

A `variable`, or `identifier`, simply points to the space that the object takes up in memory.  In java, objects get passed to methods **by reference.**  So if you create a new object in the call to a method, that method will have access to the object stored in memory since you are providing the reference to that object's location.  Subsequent actions after the method completes will not have access to the object since you did not store the reference in a named variable.

Comment: oh I see so its like a local reference?

Comment: Kind of.  The idea is that whenever you use the `new` keyword it creates an object and stores it in memory.  You access this object by using a reference (kind of like a pointer) to its location.  You can store this pointer in a named variable so that you can access the object later on.  The other way to do it passes the reference to the method, but doesn't store it in a variable for later use.

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing the object with name (Just passing instance to method). If you reference the object, through that reference you can further perform operations on that object in specified scop.

If you think you don't need to do any further operations on that object in specified scope, then you can simply create an object without reference.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you do it equivalent to:

```
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(600,600);
setSize(dimension);
```

Now even though it is exactly the same thing, `dimension` is just an identifier for that new object. If you don't need to use it anywhere else except the new object, this is just a waste of space.

The `setSize` method, passes the new object to a variable of your superclass, `JFrame`, which keeps your object and your class `GameFrame` will have access to it via its superclass. In Java, every object needs to have at least one reference to it, or else it is considered garbage and it is deleted.

Also, even if you gave a name to `dimension`, after your four lines of code executed, the variable gets out of scope and gets deleted.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: oh so if would have been deleted either way I create the Dimension object. This helped greatly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature called anonymous classes, where you don't really care about the reference of the object - but what you really care about is the functionality/behavior of the object.  You will see this more in functional programming.

More about this feature is [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~tmh/courses/allJava/Anonymous.html)

Comment: This is not about anonymous classes.

Comment: If so, can you please explain what are these  setSize(new Dimension(600,600)); ?

Comment: See the other up-voted answers. An anonymous class would be setSize(new Dimension(600,600){}); note the trailing {}, in which you can override methods etc.

Comment: Yeah as Tom said, you usually use anonymous classes to create a class on the spot or implement an interface, but it has to be needed only on that spot. A usual way using them is with ActionListeners.